# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to configure KeyVault property source

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azure-keyvault

I am having issues when i am using azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-starter of 2.3.3 version.

### application.properties

```
azure.keyvault.uri=...........
azure.keyvault.enabled=true
azure.client-id=........
azure.client-key=.......

10:00:47.863 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to configure KeyVault property source
    at com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.spring.KeyVaultEnvironmentPostProcessorHelper.addKeyVaultPropertySource(KeyVaultEnvironmentPostProcessorHelper.java:110)
    at com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.spring.KeyVaultEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(KeyVaultEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:47)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:200)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:188)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
```

Comment: There is an issue reported on GitHub - https://github.com/microsoft/azure-spring-boot/issues/621. This is the solution for this - https://github.com/microsoft/azure-spring-boot/tree/release/2.3.2/azure-spring-boot-starters/azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-starter
Let me know if this works for you, I will post it as answer.

Comment: Have you configured right access policy for the ad application in Azure key vault?

Comment: Try to add the `azure.keyvault.tenant-id=<your-tenant-id>` in the application.properties. For more details, see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-spring-boot/tree/release/2.3.2/azure-spring-boot-samples/azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-sample#add-the-property-setting).

Comment: Thanks, It got resolved now, added tenant-id and other configurations like azure.keyvault.tenant-id=............
azure.keyvault.token-acquire-timeout-seconds=60
azure.keyvault.refresh-interval=1800000

Comment: @Jayashree, did the above link (https://github.com/microsoft/azure-spring-boot/tree/release/2.3.2/azure-spring-boot-starters/azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-starter) help you ?

Comment: I added my comment as an answer, you could accept it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the error, you need to add the `azure.keyvault.tenant-id=<your-tenant-id>` in the **application.properties**. You can also add `azure.keyvault.token-acquire-timeout-seconds=60`, `azure.keyvault.refresh-interval=1800000` to configure.

```
azure.keyvault.enabled=true
azure.keyvault.uri=https://{your-azure-keyvault}.vault.azure.net/
azure.keyvault.client-id=put-your-azure-client-id-here
azure.keyvault.client-key=put-your-azure-client-key-here
azure.keyvault.tenant-id=put-your-azure-tenant-id-here
```

For more details, see the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-key-vault) and the [sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-spring-boot/tree/release/2.3.2/azure-spring-boot-samples/azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-sample#azure-key-vault-secrets-spring-boot-starter-sample).