# SslHandshakeTimeoutException When Accessing KeyVault (SpringBoot 2.7)

Tags: spring-boot, azure, azure-keyvault

I am trying to learn how to fetch secrets from Azure KeyVault. So I set one KeyVault up with my account. I think i did it correct. But when I try to connect it from my SpringBoot application I get the following error:

```
2023-06-14 19:45:27.239 INFO 7360 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-06-14 19:45:27.255 INFO 7360 --- [  restartedMain] c.example.demo.KeyvaultDemoApplication   : Started KeyvaultDemoApplication in 2.898 seconds (JVM running for 3.904)
2023-06-14 19:45:38.765 ERROR 7360 --- [  restartedMain] c.a.c.http.netty.NettyAsyncHttpClient    : io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandshakeTimeoutException: handshake timed out after 10000ms
2023-06-14 19:45:38.775 WARN 7360 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : [379c4b95, L:/MY_IP:57095 - R:my_key_vault.vault.azure.net/SOME_IP:443] The connection observed an error

io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandshakeTimeoutException: handshake timed out after 10000ms
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$7.run(SslHandler.java:2125) ~[netty-handler-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98) ~[netty-common-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:153) ~[netty-common-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174) ~[netty-common-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167) ~[netty-common-4.1.92.Final.jar:4.1.92.Final]
```

I have set this in my `application.properties`:

```
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.endpoint=https://my_key_vault.vault.azure.net/
```

My SpringBoot Main class looks like:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClient;

@SpringBootApplication
public class KeyvaultDemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {


    // Spring Cloud Azure will automatically inject SecretClient in your ApplicationContext.
    @Autowired
    private final SecretClient secretClient;


    public KeyvaultDemoApplication(SecretClient secretClient) {
        this.secretClient = secretClient;
    }


    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("h2url: " + secretClient.getSecret("dbPassword").getValue());
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KeyvaultDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And I wrote a configuration class:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder;
import com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClient;
import com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClientBuilder;


@Configuration
public class SecretClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecretClient createSecretClient() {
        return new SecretClientBuilder().vaultUrl("https://my_key_vault.vault.azure.net/
").credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build()).buildClient();
        }
    }
```

Most of these are from the Azure tutorial. I am pretty sure, it must be the way I set up the KeyVault. I am not an expert on access control and other items in Azure.

Any pointers would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed alternative way to fetch secrets from azure key vault in spring boot application :

***Refer to my [github](https://github.com/PravallikaKothaveerannagari/Retrive_secretfrom_Azure_keyvault) repo for complete code to fetch secrets from Azure key vault:***

1. Run the command `az account list` in the Azure Cloud Shell to get list of subscriptions of your account.
2. Run  `az account set -s <your_subscription_id>` select and use specific Subscription:
3. Create service principal using the command:
   `az ad sp create-for-rbac --name myapp --role Contributor --scopes /subscriptions/SubscriptionID`
4. Open your service principal app in Active directory and note the details of `your_Client_ID`,   `your_Client_Secret_Value`  and `your_Tenant_ID`
5. Follow below steps to Access Azure key vault in sprint boot application:

- Create a Resource Group in portal.
- Create a new Key Vault in your resource group.
- Create a secret in Azure key vault and store your secret key.
- Select “Access policies” => click on **Create** and Select the required permissions such as “*Get, List, Recover, Set, Delete, Backup, Restore*” in  **secret permissions**.

[image]

- Click on “***Next***” and select your service principal app and “***Create***”.

[image]

5. Open your spring boot application=>  `resources` folder=> open `application.properties` , paste the values of `your_Client_ID`, `Client_Secret_Value`, `Tenant_ID` and `Key Vault URL`  as shown below:

[image]

```java
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].credential.client-id=<Client_ID>  
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].credential.client-secret=<Client_Secret_value>  
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].endpoint=<your_KeyVault_URL>  
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].profile.tenant-id=<Tenant_ID>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the error didn't go away. I currently get `18:03:56.278 [restartedMain] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to configure KeyVault property source`
and at the bottom I see `Caused by: reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandshakeTimeoutException: handshake timed out after 10000ms`

I think i followed your instructions just right.

Comment: @hell_storm2004, check the solutions provided in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63771441/java-lang-illegalstateexception-failed-to-configure-keyvault-property-source#:~:text=To%20solve%20the%20error%2C%20you%20need%20to%20add,You%20can%20also%20add%20azure.keyvault.token-acquire-timeout-seconds%3D60%2C%20azure.keyvault.refresh-interval%3D1800000%20to%20configure) link which may help to fix your issue.

Comment: The name `myapp` is it the name of the spring boot application name that we declare on our pom.xml? Or it can be anything?

Comment: yes, `myapp` is the name of my springboot application which I have used in pom.xml.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get it to work. But the timeout thing was because of my corporate proxy. Which is a different issue. But without the proxy it works. And the steps were really helpful.